# Infopath Regular Expression End of String

Tags: regex, infopath

I need to write a regular expression to match an unknown number of 6 digit "strings" separated by a forward slash

`123456` - pass

`123456/123457` - pass

`123456/123r43` - fail

`123456/12` - fail

And it could be a series of more than 2 sets of item numbers...

I've got the following regex that appears to work, in PHP or another lanaguage, however, infopath does not seem to like `$` as an end-of-string matcher.

`([0-9]{6}\/?)+$`

If I remove the `$` the example `123456/12` will pass, when it should fail.  Is there a different way to write that regex that will solve this problem, or will I have to go in and write some validation code underneath the form? (which I am not opposed to doing)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative look-ahead to mimic `$`:

```
[0-9]{6}(\/[0-9]{6})*(?!.)
```

Using `[0-9]` instead of `\d` because the latter could have unicode digit chars.

If needed, you can use a negative look-behind to mimic `^` as well:

```
(?<!.)[0-9]{6}(\/[0-9]{6})*(?!.)
```